# Getting ExectuionEngineException was unhandled Error in GetTimeZoneInformation API Execution

Tags: vb.net, lib

I have declared API as:

```
Private Declare Function GetTimeZoneInformation Lib "kernel32" (ByRef a_timezoneinfo As t_TimeZoneInfo) As Integer
```

`t_TimeZoneInfo` Structure Definition is as follows:

```
    Private Structure t_TimeZoneInfo
        Dim tz_Bias As Integer
        <VBFixedArray(32)> Dim tz_StandardName() As Short

            Dim tz_StandardDateArray As t_SysTimeAsArray
        Dim tz_StandardBias As Integer
        <VBFixedArray(32)> Dim tz_DaylightName() As Short

        Dim tz_DayLightDateArray As t_SysTimeAsArray
        Dim tz_DaylightBias As Integer


        Public Sub Initialize()

            ReDim tz_StandardName(32)
            tz_StandardDateArray.Initialize()

            ReDim tz_DaylightName(32)
            tz_DayLightDateArray.Initialize()
        End Sub
    End Structure
```

And Structure `t_SysTimeAsArray` is:

```
    Private Structure t_SysTimeAsArray
        <VBFixedArray(8)> Dim w_timeval() As Short ' Y M Dw D G Min S mS

        Public Sub Initialize()

        ReDim w_timeval(8)
        End Sub
    End Structure
```

Then I have the below code in my other function:

```
Dim lfmtres As String = "" 
Dim lneedunicode As Boolean
Dim lres As Integer
lfmtres = CStr(a_tzinfo.tz_Bias) & "," & CStr(a_tzinfo.tz_DaylightBias) & "," & mCopyShortArrayToChars(a_tzinfo.tz_StandardName, 32, lneedunicode) & "," & mCopyShortArrayToChars(a_tzinfo.tz_DaylightName, 32, lneedunicode) & "," & mCopyShortArrayToNumString(a_tzinfo.tz_StandardDateArray.w_timeval, 8) & "," & mCopyShortArrayToNumString(a_tzinfo.tz_DayLightDateArray.w_timeval, 8)
lres = GetTimeZoneInformation(ltzinfo)
```

It throws Exception of type `System.ExecutionEngineException` at line `lres = GetTimeZoneInformation(ltzinfo)`. Well, I know that this type of exception generally happens when there is an internal error in the execution engine of the common language runtime but I believe that in my case I'm doing something wrong in lib API Declaration. (As I have already tried reinstalling VS, run project in other laptop, Change version but nothing fixed the problem). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What line does it reach when the error pops it?  Are you working in 64bit VB?  If so, we'll need to add `PtrSafe`.  `Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTimeZoneInformation Lib "kernel32" (ByRef a_timezoneinfo As t_TimeZoneInfo) As Integer`

Comment: @JimmySmith When it throws error Exection stops at line lres = GetTimeZoneInformation(ltzinfo) . And I'm running project in 32bit VS(It is a vb.net code not vb6)

Comment: hrmm... I'm just guessing at this moment, as the error is happening within the DLL unfortunately.  Workaround?  What about the VB.NET TimeZone classes for what you're trying to accomplish?  They do all these API calls for you I think.

Comment: VBFixedArray does not do what you think it does, the pinvoke marshaller has no support for it.  It is only intended to be used with legacy VB6 file I/O code.  As a result, the structure you use is far too small and the 172 bytes in the real structure will corrupt the GC heap.  You must use `<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=32)>` instead.  And double-check after the changes that `Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(t_TimeZoneInfo))` returns 172.

Comment: It gets value 268 not 172 !!